# Como extrair todos os itens de uma tag de resposta de um JSON com Python

Tags: python, json

Caros bom dia, estou iniciando na programação com python, e estou estudando uma API Json da Caixa, que tem seu retorno uma lista com vários dicionários dentro e dentro do dicionário também tem lista. Essa API é muito boa para aprender a tratar esse tipo de saida, visto que as APIs do trabalho tem esse tipo de estrutura de retorno, com um monte de informação.

Eu estou tentando mas não consegui rss. estrair as informações desse response.

Codigo:

```
import  json, requests
response = requests.get("https://loteriascaixa-api.herokuapp.com/api/mega-sena/", verify=False)
comments = json.loads(response.content)
print('concurso              = ',comments[0]['concurso'])
print('dezenas               = ',comments[0]['dezenas'])
```

Eu consigo pegar 1 dos valores que eu quero, mas gostaria de pegar todos os valores de ['concurso'] e ['dezenas'], mas não consegui fazer um laço para trazer essas informações fora de uma lista.

Abaixo um exemplo de como gostaria de ter o resultado.

```
9, 08, 43, 54, 55, 56, 60
8, 04, 17, 37, 38, 47, 53
7, 03, 05, 20, 21, 38, 56
6, 07, 13, 19, 22, 40, 47
5, 01, 02, 06, 16, 19, 46
4, 01, 05, 06, 27, 42, 59
3, 10, 11, 29, 30, 36, 47
2, 09, 37, 39, 41, 43, 49
1, 04, 05, 30, 33, 41, 52
```

Onde 1 é o concurso e os demais são as números que estão dentro da lista dezenas.

Não consegui uma explicação na internet para percorrer esse tipo de informação tão complexa. Por isso gostaria de aprender.

Se possível, no final salvar esse resultado em um arquivo .csv ou .txt

Agradeço desde já atenção de todos.

Comment: Ler um JSON não é complexo. Primeiro vc pode pegar o retorno da API e jogar em sites como [esse](https://jsonlint.com/) (ou em qualquer editor decente que consiga formatar JSON), assim vc consegue ver a estrutura. E [entender a estrutura não é difícil](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json). No caso, a API retorna um array, então basta fazer um `for` pela lista `comments`, e para cada elemento vc pega o concurso e as dezenas. Algo como `for e in comments: print(e['concurso'], e['dezenas'])` - para formatar as dezenas, pesquise por `join`

Comment: Olá. Sua pergunta está mal formatada dificultando a forma de ver o código e o exemplo de entrada. Dê uma olhada em como utilizar [*syntax highlighting*](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) para melhorar a legibilidade da sua pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui fazer dessa forma. Não sei se é a mais legal, mas tem o resultado no formato que eu quero. Falta agora salvar em um arquivo no computador.

```
import  json, requests

response = requests.get("https://loteriascaixa-api.herokuapp.com/api/mega-sena/", verify=False)
comments = json.loads(response.content)

for dezena in comments:
    #print(dezena['dezenas'])
    conc = dezena['concurso']
    dez1 = dezena['dezenas'][0]
    dez2 = dezena['dezenas'][1]
    dez3 = dezena['dezenas'][2]
    dez4 = dezena['dezenas'][3]
    dez5 = dezena['dezenas'][4]
    dez6 = dezena['dezenas'][5]
    data = dezena['data']
    acum = dezena['acumulou']
    lote = dezena['loteria']
    valor = dezena['acumuladaProxConcurso']
    print(f'{conc},{dez1},{dez2},{dez3},{dez4},{dez5},{dez6},{data},{acum},{lote},{valor}')
```

Comment: Pode trocar o print por `print(dezena['concurso'], ','.join(dezena['dezenas']), dezena['data'], dezena['acumulou'], dezena['loteria'], dezena['acumuladaProxConcurso'], sep=',')`. Ou ainda `print(f"{dezena['concurso']},{','.join(dezena['dezenas'])},{dezena['data']},{dezena['acumulou']},{dezena['loteria']},{dezena['acumuladaProxConcurso']}")`. Para escrever em arquivo, tem [vários posts sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+escrever+arquivo)